# laravel does not override files on publich command

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, vendor

I'm trying to build a laravel package and I faced a problem which is when I trying to publish views or migrations or controllers files it does not override files in the app!! it copied the files successfully but it keeps using package's files!

and I tried assets and config files and it copied the files and overridden as it should so no problem with that.
The problem only with the above files!

here is my package's service provider publishes :

```php
       // Migrations
       $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations/package')
        ], 'package-migrations');

        // Controllers
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../src/Http/Controllers' => app_path('Http/Controllers/package')
        ], 'package-controllers');

        // Views
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../views' => base_path('resources/views/package')
        ], 'package-views');
```

Anyone can help?

thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/master/src/SitemapServiceProvider.php for an example

Comment: @onlineThomas The same of mine!

Comment: If it was the same, it would work haha ;) Maybe have a second look at the total package how they load views etc.

Comment: It the same and not working :) I already did that.
the view's path to should be contained 'vendor/loadViewsName'

Comment: So by your logic the package by spatie also shouldn't work right?

Comment: I did a mistake and all worked as I want but the controllers not override the files! I know It not going to be overridden and I have a solution which is to extend the class and override a specific method :)